# Error in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, .net-2.0

Please tell me what is use of:

```
<add assembly="*"/>
```

because of this i am getting error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Config\web.config
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb.aspx):

> you can specify the asterisk (*) wildcard character to add every assembly within the private assembly cache for the application, which is located either in the \bin subdirectory of an application or in the.NET Framework installation directory (%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version)

Since you most likely don't need to add all assemblies to your application I would suggest adding only the ones you are actually using and leave the `<add assembly="*" />` part out, which should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Indexing Service may cause such a problem. If Indexing Service is running on your computer then, you should exlude it from indexing directories:

1. Open Computer Management from Administrative Tools on your computer.
2. Navigate to Indexing Service under Services and Applications.
3. Select "Web" under Indexing Service.
4. On the right pane Right Click mouse and chose New > Directory.
5. Add the paths where your web pages are (Ex: c:\inetpub).
6. Repeat this for all virtual directories not under inetpub.